# set subversion in IntelliJ

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I would like to achieve svn connection with my IntelliJ on OSX (10.10.5). Now I'm using SmartSVN (9.1) as subversion client, but yet I couldn't set the connection between the application and the IntellJ like I did on Windows (10). Maybe wrong app to use, or just I forget something but I'm stuck.

Comment: What did you do so far and what problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

SmartSVN is not the Subversion client IntelliJ IDEA requires. SmartSVN is a non-standard SVN client that's using SVNKit (SVN rewritten in pure Java) and it does not include standard Subversion command line tools (e.g. a command line client `svn`).

You should install up-to-date standard command line Subversion client or switch IDEA to use it's built-in SVNKit through **Settings | Version Control | Subversion**, uncheck **Use command line client**.

Comment: SVNKit was removed from JIDEA in 2018, you must install a command-line svn client now.